# How to get individual request size without aggregating all the request sizes?

Tags: prometheus

```
class YourClass {
  static final Summary receivedBytes = Summary.build()
   .name("requests_size_bytes").help("Request size in 
  bytes.").register();
  static final Summary requestLatency = Summary.build()
   .name("requests_latency_seconds").help("Request latency in 
  seconds.").register();

void processRequest(Request req) {
    Summary.Timer requestTimer = requestLatency.startTimer();
    try {
     //some code goes here.
    } finally {
       receivedBytes.observe(req.size());
       requestTimer.observeDuration();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the size of individual request separately but when a request is sent to the API    `receivedBytes.observe(req.size())` returns an aggregated value of size of all the requests until the last request.

can I get the size of request  separately instead of  aggregated value

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is a metrics monitoring system, so doesn't care about individual events. Rather it cares about things like what the request size is on average, or bytes per second.

What you need here is a logging system which can record the per-request information for you.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, can we get the previous value of the metrics by Quering the Prometheus ?. then I can subtract the previous value from current value and get the latest request size.

Comment: Prometheus scrapes say once a minute, so that only works if you haven't had more than one request in that time period.